# Остановить видео при закрытии модального окна

Tags: javascript

Здраствуйте! Модальное оконо на CSS. В него встроено видео.
 Но при закрытии видео оно продолжает проигрывать. 
 Как отлючить видео при нажатии на кнопку закрыть.

Разметка модального окна.

```
 <a href="#ModalOpen1"><img src='img/reviews/review1.png' alt=""/></a> 
 <div id="ModalOpen1" class="Window">
 <div><a href="#close" title="Закрыть" class="close"><span>X</span></a>
 <iframe width="790" height="444" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Dq9eLgyuD1k" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
 </div>
 </div>
```

Подскажите как реализовать данную задачу?

Comment: удалите iframe например.

Comment: тоже вариант, но он мне не подходит!

Comment: очень жаль!

Comment: удалять я бы не советовал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, стоит просто подменять src?

```
document.getElementById('videoFrame').src = "not.found/404"
```

При повторном обращении к окну можно заново установить верный адрес.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую реализовать.

Comment: ДА, модальное окно на CSS!!

Comment: Если у вас получилось (а судя по эмоциям у вас получилось), то я рад :).